# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined react hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an error in `EventLink`. Pretty sure there shouldn't be any issues. Am I not calling the props correctly?

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Code:

```
function EventItem({ props }) {
  return (
    <div className="event">
      <div className="top-info">
        <CompactDateField props={props} />
      </div>
      <h2 className="title no-marg-top">
        <EventLink
          title={props.title}
          eventId={props.event_id}
          slug={`/${props.slug}`}
          dateId={props.id}
        />
      </h2>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props is an object - there's no need to destructure it. Simply remove the curly brackets from arguments.

```
function EventItem(props) {
```

Comment: Thank you kind user, I was calling my other functions this way as well, guess this one slipped through with a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function EventItem({ ...props }) {
}
```